# Tensorflow. Converting images from PNG to JPEG

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm working on CNN using Python and Tensorflow. How can I convert images from PNG to JPEG in this code?

I have some ideas about using for loop and maybe PIL image module, but I have no experience so I don't know how to make it. I'd like to make this transformation in any possible way.

ATTENTION: Layers aren't included because it's big block of code, but in my Jupyter notebook I have them.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
import numpy as np
import os

train_dir = os.path.join('D:/nnfp')
train_tank_dir = os.path.join('D:/nnfp/Tank')
train_plane_dir = os.path.join('D:/nnfp/Planes')

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1.0/255)
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir,
                                               target_size = (300,300),
                                               batch_size = 128,
                                               class_mode = 'binary')
model.compile(optimizer = RMSprop(lr = 0.001),
         loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
         metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit_generator(train_generator,
               steps_per_epoch = 15,
               epochs = 15,
               #validation_data = validation_generator,
               #validation_steps = 2,
               verbose = 1,
               callbacks = [callbacks])
```

I would like to convert all my data by adding some code in already existing if it's possible.

Comment: What is the relation between the code in your question and converting from PNG to JPEG? As far as I see, there is no relation.

Comment: As far as I know this code get images from my directory and then I need to convert them to JPEG. I guess it`s quite obvious relation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PIL` library for converting images from `png` to `jpeg` by using `convert()` method defined in the `PIL` library.

For example:

```py
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open("<Image-Name>.png")
image_rgb = im.convert('RGB')
image_rgb.save('<Image-Name-Converted>.jpg')
```

I hope it helps!

You can read the docs here for details: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.convert